# I can't run bundle it show bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I install bundle by using

```
sudo bundle install and sudo gem install bundler
```

It show error

```
bundle: command not found
```

I set path like this.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

When I run command `gem environment` it show like this.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

When I run command `echo $PATH` it show like this.

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

How to fix error **bundle: command not found** ?

Comment: Need to install bundler first thenrun gem install .

Answer (score 3):

Simply hit the command

$gem install bundle

if the ruby version is required to updated do it separately

Answer (score 0):

bundle(r) is a gem. I am guessing you have the gem not installed yet.

try

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to install ruby as system package, and I would suggest not doing that since ruby 1.8 is very old version.
You should use rvm or rbenv instead for ruby installation.
Take a look on http://rvm.io. After rvm installed, install ruby

> rvm install 2.3.1

then install bundler

> gem install bundler